# Is not possible to use the WsdlService type provider on OSX/.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: soap, f#, .net-core, type-providers

I try use the WsdlService type provider from FSharp.Data on OSX in a .net core 2.1 console app, and get this error:

> ../Test.fs(16,16): Error FS3033: The type provider
>   'FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders' reported an
>   error: The .NET SDK 4.0 or 4.5 tools could not be found (FS3033)
>   (Sync)

I try to apply the workaround at https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/tree/master/tests/SqlProvider.Core.Tests/MsSql after read the issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3303. This is my project file (simplified):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <ReleaseVersion>0.5</ReleaseVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <FscToolPath>/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands</FscToolPath>
    <FscToolExe>fsharpc</FscToolExe>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data" Version="2.4.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data.TypeProviders" Version="5.0.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Alternatively, what to use for manually do SOAP calls in F#?

Comment: The WSDL is really an old type provider from the F# 3 days, I doubt it will work on .netcore. You might try just pure .netcore WCF, e.g. not the type provider.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer - Nope it isn't.

This is due to several reasons, the main one being `svcutil.exe` which the type provider uses to generate the type information. Doesn't generate code that is compatible with the .NET Core WCF libraries [Dotnet Wcf](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf). There is a new version of this being worked on but the last I checked it didn't work correctly outside of Visual Studio.

When the above work is completed or at least at a state where it is dependant of Visual Studio shouldn't be too hard to change the current TypeProvider to get it to work on .NET core.

As for actually making SOAP calls I typically use [SOAP UI](https://www.soapui.org/) to generate the Envelope and save it it to a local file then just use the XML provider or simple string replacement to fill in the body of the envelop, then send it using a HTTP Client